# How do I transform my output into a new table with an index? PYTHON 3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, columnsorting

I'm clearly a begginer in learning python, please be nice to me.

I was able to import data of the cash flow of a company and summed 2 rows but when I try to Print(df.columns()) there is the error "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'"

My output (print(df))  looks like a table but I would like to understand it better, create new columns etc

```
Output:
endDate
2020-12-31    77078000.0
2019-12-31    -1902000.0
2018-12-31    -2222000.0
2017-12-31    53877000.0
dtype: float64
```

**So how can I create an Index with 2 columns (Date; FCF)?**

Comment: use `df=df.to_frame()` then add your new columns Date and FCF after that use `df=df.set_index(['Date','FCF'])`

Comment: Thanks for your help but it still don't work



OUTPUT:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/lucas/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/valuation.py", line 30, in <module>
    df =df.set_index(['Date','FCF'])
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4551, in set_index
    raise KeyError(f"None of {missing} are in the columns")
KeyError: "None of ['Date', 'FCF'] are in the columns"

Comment: Here is the full code

import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si
import pandas as pd
import requests
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')


df = si.get_cash_flow('ETER3.SA')


df = (df.loc['totalCashFromOperatingActivities'] + df.loc['capitalExpenditures'])

df = df.to_frame()
df =df.set_index(['Date','FCF'])

print(df)

------------------------------

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error(df.columns()) because pandas series do not have columns. In your case, there's an index (Date) and a corresponding value (FCF). To convert it into a DataFrame you can try this:

```
new_df = df.reset_index()
```

if you don't like the generated column names, you can rename the columns with:

```
new_df.rename(columns = {'old_name1' : 'new_name1', 
                         'old_name2' : 'new_name2'})
```

Comment: Sorry, it didnt work

I reseted the index and printed, the result was the same as before
I tried to print print(new_df.columns()) to check the new names, but is still an error: